# How to call a function when the form is submitted in yii2?

Tags: javascript, yii2

I want to call a function when a form is sent and validated, but I'm unsure how this works.

This is my code:

```
echo '<div class="form-group">';
if ($model->isNewRecord) {
    echo kartik\helpers\Html::submitButton('Create', [
        'class' => 'btn btn-success',
        'data-confirm' => 'send data?'
    ]);
```

Comment: This is submit button...

Comment: Title and grammar

Comment: First of all go and read the difference between View and Controller roles in documentation (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html), then try to rethink of question you want to ask.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for JavaScript event, that is run after form is validated (but not submitted yet), you can try running something like this:

```
$('#contact-form').on('beforeSubmit', function (e) {
    if (!confirm("Everything is correct. Submit?")) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

You can find more info and events signaled by `ActiveForm` in [community cookbook by Samdark and contributors here](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/forms-activeform-js.md#using-events).

And if you need to run JS code after submission, then you have to implement AJAX request and then process the response returned. You can start with modifying code given above for quick start (do not forget to change jQuery selectors for your case).

Try to give more info on result you want to achieve and initial task, before submitting next question on StackOverflow. Good luck!

Comment: That is to say, if you want JS modifications of form submission lifecycle, go check @Sfili_81's answer for backend side load and validation.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller

```
public function actionCreate(){

    $model = new YourModel();
    if(($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
         //call your function here
    }
}
```